# "Invalid Cast" In Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to filter a datatable with following code

```
private void Filter(string text)
    {
        int outText=0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(text, out outText))
        {
            text = string.Empty;
        }
     DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            DT = PinCDAO.GetArea().AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("AreaID")==Convert.ToInt32(outText) || (r.Field<string>("AreaDescription").Contains(text))).AsDataView().ToTable();

}
```

I'm getting the error "Specified cast is not valid".because of the code

```
r => r.Field<int>("AreaID")==Convert.ToInt32(outText)
```

I'm sure about that AreaID column Contains Integers

plz help me to solve this.

Comment: Why are you calling `Convert.ToInt32(outText)` when `outText` is already an integer?

Comment: Would one of the records have a null "AreaID"?

Comment: does AreaID allow nulls ? Can you please tell us more about it?

Comment: have you tried solution ..it work for you ...??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out code - **Handle null in you code**

because "**AreaID**" is nullable field.

```
DT = PinCDAO.GetArea().AsEnumerable().Where(r => 
   (Convert.IsDBNull(r["AreaID"]) ? 0 :  Convert.ToInt32(r["AreaID"])) ==outText
  || (r.Field<string>("AreaDescription").Contains(text))).AsDataView().ToTable();
```

this code handles null value easily..

already answered question by me : ["Specified cast is not valid" error in LINQ's orderby clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885837/specified-cast-is-not-valid-error-in-linqs-orderby-clause)

Comment: He didn't mention AreaID is nullable. did he?

Comment: @ebad86 - but this kind of problem mostly occur with the nullable field in database ...i found same problem in my code moth back and this resolve the issue easily...

Comment: @ebad86 - check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885837/specified-cast-is-not-valid-error-in-linqs-orderby-clause

Comment: You have a valid and strong point. I have asked him, lets see how he respoonds.

Answer (score 1):

Remove Convert.ToInt32, outText is already parsed as int using  `if (Int32.TryParse(text, out outText))`

```
DT = PinCDAO.GetArea().AsEnumerable()
          .Where(r => r.Field<int>("AreaID")==outText 
                           || (r.Field<string>("AreaDescription")
           .Contains(text))).AsDataView().ToTable();
```

The reason you are getting the exception could be that "AreaID" may not contain an int value

Comment: put a break point and see what is inside your table, does the field "AreaID" contains integer values or something else ?

Comment: or try r.Field<int?>("AreaID") if it is nullable

Answer (score 1):

You don't need conversion to `int` as `outText` already declared to `int`....You can simply use the `outText` in following way:

```
r => r.Field<int>("AreaID")==outText
```

You can change the expresson in following way:

```
 r => Convert.ToInt32(r["AreaID"])==outText
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables passed as an out arguments need not be initialized prior to being passed. Moreover, outtext need not to be convert to Int32 as it is one already.

```
private void Filter(string text)     {      
   int outText;         
          if (Int32.TryParse(text, out outText))        
                  { 
                    // text was integer and parsed successfully.            
                    text = string.Empty;       
                   }     
 DataTable DT = new DataTable();  
           DT = PinCDAO.GetArea().AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("AreaID")== outText || (r.Field<string>("AreaDescription").Contains(text))).AsDataView().ToTable();  }
```